# After Creating Custom PDF Save Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.3, pdf, file-upload

Using [dompdf](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf) Convert Custom Email **Template** To **Pdf**

But After Create `PDF` I Want to Save That `PDF` into **`pub/media/customFolder`**

> **Here My Code :-**

**Define in email_templates.xml :-**

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Email:etc/email_templates.xsd">
    <template id="custom_template_id" label="custom_template_id" file="pdftemplate.html" type="html" module="Vendor_Module" area="frontend"/>
</config>
```

**Get Email Template As Html :-**

```
$testTemplate = $this->templateFactory->get('custom_template_id') //template Identifier
                ->setVars($templateVars)
                ->setOptions($templateOptions);

        $html = $testTemplate->processTemplate();
```

**Create PDF :-**

```
$dompdf = new Dompdf();

$dompdf->loadHtml($html); //$html is html of template

$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');

$dompdf->render();

file_put_contents('custom_pdf.pdf', $dompdf->output());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please add with below code :

```
$path = '/var/www/html/magento2/pub/media/template.pdf';
file_put_contents($path, $dompdf->output()); 
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="template.pdf"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($path));
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
readfile($path);
```

**make sure directory permission is 777**

Comment: Nice and easy answer. +1 for that

Comment: 1+ for answer let me check

Comment: in which folder save PDF ??

Comment: i m try your code code execute successfully but file not found..

Comment: possible to set path /var/www/html/magento2/pub/media/customfolder

Comment: but i m not define any path to save this file check my updated answer

Comment: file does not exist in customfolder

Comment: please check my answer in comment, i mention already set path.

Comment: ohk let me check :)

Comment: like this - file_put_contents('/var/www/html/magento2/pub/media/customfolder/file.pdf', $dompdf->output());

Comment: please check i update full code.

Comment: thank you its working fine....:)